# Python: How to add list of tokens to new column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, token

I have a large dataframe with over 50 rows. For each row I have a column 'tokens', this contains a large number of textual tokens. I have used a for-loop along with frequency distribution to find the top-10 tokens in each row for the 'tokens' column.

I am trying to add a new column to my dataframe called 'top10', so that for each row, the top-10 tokens are contained in the 'top10' column.

This is the current code I am using to find my top-10 tokens for each row.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
   tokens = df.iloc[i]['tokens']
   frequency = nltk.FreqDist(tokens)
   print(" ", word_frequency.most_common(10))
```

A sample of my dataframe:

```
id location about age tokens
1    usa     ...  20   ['jim','hi','hello'......]
...
... 
40    uk     ...  50   ['bobby','hi','hey'......]
```

Expected output:

```
id location about age tokens                           top10
1    usa     ...  20   ['jim','hi','hello'......]   ['hi', 'paddy'....]
...
... 
40    uk     ...  50   ['bobby','hi','hey'......]   ['john', 'python'..]
```

The top10 column should display words in descending order.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

pandas `apply` with keyword arguments `reduce` (don't expand lists) and `axis=1` (over rows, not columns as default), is nicer because you are already iterating over rows. Pandas interprets your lists as series, that don't fit in the single cells.

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk

df =  pd.DataFrame({x :{'tokens': ['hello', 'python', 'is', 'is', 'is', 'dog', 'god', 'cat', 'act', 'fraud', 'hola', 'the', 'a', 'the', 'on', 'no', 'of', 'foo', 'foo']} for x in range(0,10)} ).T


def most_common_words_list (x):
    word_count_tups = nltk.FreqDist(x['tokens']).most_common(2)
    return [word for word, count in word_count_tups]

df ['top2'] = df.apply(most_common_words_list,  result_type='reduce', axis=1)
```

Comment: Did you make a typo with the brackets of `FreqDist(x['tokens'])`? Here it works

Comment: The  'apply' command replaces your whole `for`-loop. The `apply` call does the looping on each row for you

Comment: you need this line `df ['top10'] = df.apply(lambda x: nltk.FreqDist(x['tokens']).most_common(10),  result_type='reduce', axis=1)` it is exactly just this

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple way of adding a new column to DF:

`df['top10'] = word_frequency.most_common(10)`

Comment: Make a list of most_common(10) and then try